# C# changing EventArgs for method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a Windows Forms application, and I would like to pass to the `MouseClick` event on `Picturebox` a parameter of type `MouseEventArgs` instead of `EventArgs`, but the debugger yells an error for delegate when I do so.

```
void PictureBox1Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Some code
}

///////
// imageBox
// 
this.imageBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.imageBox.Name = "imageBox";
this.imageBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1758, 829);
this.imageBox.TabIndex = 0;
this.imageBox.TabStop = false;
this.imageBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.PictureBox1Click);
//
```

Thanks in advance, Jackob

Comment: The `EventArgs e` object of a Click event is already of type `MouseEventArgs`. Test it with `var args = e as MouseEventArgs;`

Comment: When the click event has been raise by a mouse click, if you handle `Click` event, then the run-time type of e is `MouseEventArgs` as it's already mentioned by Jimi. But in some controls, like `Button`, you may raise click without a mouse click, in such cases, the run-time type of `e` is `EventArgs`. If you are interested to mouse click and you want to receive `e` as `MouseEventArgs`, then you should handle `MouseClick` event.

Comment: Hi, will try and update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the click event has been raised by a mouse click, if you handle `Click` event, then the run-time type of `e` is `MouseEventArgs` as it's already mentioned by Jimi in the comments.

But in some controls, like `Button`, you may raise `Click` event without an actual mouse click, for example by calling `button1.PerformClick()` or when the button is the `AcceptButton` of the form and you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or if you press mnemonic key combination for the button or when the button has focus and you press <kbd>Space</kbd>. In such cases, the run-time type of `e` is `EventArgs`.

If you are interested to mouse click and you want to receive `e` as `MouseEventArgs`, then you should handle `MouseClick` event.

For example:

```
picttureBox1.MouseClick += PicttureBox1_MouseClick;
```

And then:

```
private void PicttureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you and Jimmy. defining the variable as MouseEventArgs did the work!

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the mouse click event from the parent control, where the mouseclick event args are passed, check if the mouse position is inside the picture box and continue from there?!

Answer (score 1):

Wich events exists, wich arguments they take, and indeed when they are called and wich values they are given is entirely up to the writer of that class. As a mere user of this code, you can not change it.

You can create a subclass of Picature Box where you can add your own event "ClickWithExtraArguments" or something like that. But raising it in place of the default one might not be easy. Sometimes the "RaiseEvent[X]" code is marked protected, so you can override it. RaiseMouseEvent is one of those, but this really goes deep into Event handling.

What inforamtion are you tryting to give via the Event Args anway? Can you not simply retreive the information in the existing Click Event handler?